# Overlaying two faceted line graphs with different Y axis in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, linegraph

I have two dataframes:

**df1** represents the Unemployment Rate across 9 English regions from 01/2019 until 10/2020.

**df2** represents the Crime Occurrencies of 5 different types of crime (same regions and same time period as df1).

I merged them, and now I have **df3**, of which you can find a sample below:

```
structure(list(
Region = c(
  "West Midlands", "South West", "South East", 
  "South West", "West Midlands", "West Midlands", "London", "East Midlands", 
  "East of England", "South East"), 
Crime.date = c("2019-02", "2019-07", "2020-07", "2019-06", "2020-06", "2019-03", 
               "2019-06", "2019-09", "2020-01", "2020-07"), 
Crime = c("Burglary", "Robbery", "Anti-social behaviour", 
          "Robbery", "Anti-social behaviour", "Robbery", "Violence and sexual offences", 
          "Theft", "Robbery", "Violence and sexual offences"), 
Crime_occurrencies = c(3365L, 204L, 25937L, 213L, 14612L, 1079L, 19976L, 5227L, 258L, 27559L), 
Unemployment.date = c("2019-11", "2019-03", "2020-04", "2020-07", "2020-09", 
"2019-08", "2019-05", "2020-03", "2020-07", "2019-12"), 
Unemployment.rate = c(4.31748261760943, 2.41576148488749, 3.01997997605704, 
                      3.79786892020692, 4.80407628492848, 3.98279027057451, 
                      4.2650375361128, 3.76788548732822, 3.72128619704797, 
                      3.21824018447441)), 
row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000212e5b01ef0>)
```

*There is only one Unemployment.date for each region for each month. However, Crime.date is repeated for every single reported crime, for every region (i.e. if there are three Theft crimes reported in the same month, even in they same region, they will appear three times in the data frame. Hence why there is a much higher number of dates under that column compared to Unemployment. date.*

I am trying to plot 9 graphs (one for each English region) with the same X axis (Date) but with different Y axis (one for Crime Occurrencies, and one for Unemployment Rate).

```
df3 %>%
  count(Region, Crime.date, Crime, name = 'Crime_occurrencies') %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(paste0(Crime.date, '-01'))) %>%
  ggplot(df3, aes(Date, Crime_occurrencies, colour = Crime)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(Unemployment.date, Unemployment.rate, col = "black")) +
  facet_wrap( ~ Region,
              scales = "free_y") +
  scale_x_date(breaks = seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2020-10-01"), by =
                              "1 month"),
               date_labels = '%m %Y') +
  sec_axis(df3$Unemployment.rate, name = "Unemployment rate (%)"))
```

This code gives me the error "Mapping should be created with `aes()` or `aes_()`."
I don't understand why it's not working, as I am mapping both lines using aes().

**Desired output:**

A line graph that represents Unemployment.rate overlayed on each one of the region's graphs below:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am borderline desperate.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: @teunbrands, this is what the graph looks like on my dataset with the code you kindly provided. You definitely nailed the Y axis issue, but overlaying the Unemployment rate line graph seems a bit more of a challenge.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So here is my attempt at your problem. The error message was correctly pointed out by Mario Niepel, so I'll focus my answer on the secondary axis. Secondary axes in ggplot2 have essentially 2 components:

1. You must transform your secondary axis data so it fits in the range of the primary data.
2. You must specify an inverse transform that can restore the rescaled values back to the original ones.

Typically you'd specify component (1) in the `aes()` and component (2) as the `trans` argument of the secondary axis. One approach of specifying these transformations is by calculating the `range()` of both the primary and secondary data and then use `scales::rescale()` for both (1) and (2), but switching the `to` and `from` arguments. You'll find an example of this in the code below (assume `df` is your `df3`).

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

# For my convenience: reshaping data back in what I think was the original data
crime <- data.frame(
  Region = df$Region,
  Date = as.Date(paste0(df$Crime.date, "-01")),
  Crime = df$Crime,
  Occurances = df$Crime_occurrencies
)
unemploy <- data.frame(
  Region = df$Region,
  Date = as.Date(paste0(df$Unemployment.date, "-01")),
  Crime = df$Crime,
  Rate = df$Unemployment.rate
)

# Here we calculate the ranges for the reshape
out_range <- range(crime$Occurances)
in_range <- range(unemploy$Rate)

ggplot(mapping = aes(Date)) +
  # Using points here otherwise wouldn't see data
  geom_point(aes(y = Occurances, colour = Crime), 
             data = crime) +
  # Transform your data in `aes()` (1)
  geom_line(aes(y = rescale(Rate, to = out_range, from = in_range),
                linetype = "Unemployment Rate"), 
            colour = "black",
            data = unemploy) +
  facet_wrap(~ Region) +
  # Inverse transform with formula notation (2)
  scale_y_continuous(
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ rescale(.x, to = in_range, from = out_range))
  )
```

[image]

The data is a bit sparse for the example, but I hope this gives you an idea how to specify the secondary axis. If you need to free the y-axes in the `facet()` function, you might run into some weird looking plots where low crime occurrence areas have unemployment rates high above. However, the axis transform cannot be tailored to every facet, so instead you could consider normalising to per capita crime occurances.

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for taking the time to go though everything, I really appreciate it. I tried applying your suggestion to my dataset, however the result isn't really understandable unfortunately :/ I edited my main post so you can check it out! I am starting to think that merging the data wasn't a smart choice, maybe I should've kept the two data frames separated?

Comment: I agree it's weird. It's hard to diagnose, but I think the crimes data wasn't aggregated for every day yet (based on dots placed vertically above oneanother with the same colour).

I don't actually recommend plotting the crimes as points, you should use the line (but because example data often had <2 observations per condition it wouldn't show with a line). Keeping the data separate is probably wise in this case, as you don't want to transform the crimes data on the primary axis.

Comment: I would do the crimes data the way you did it in your first image, but do the unemployment data with the transformation trick I showed above.

Comment: Aah got it, thanks again for your help! Gotta figure out how to to combine two plots in two different data frames now haha

Comment: Ok I'm gonna give it a try tomorrow! Off to bed now, wish me luck!

Comment: Good luck! Combining two data.frames in a plot is just giving them as the `data = ...` argument for geoms (it is also what I did in the code above).

Comment: Ok so I tried running your code using the two dataframes separately (crime and unemployment, without full_joining them). Unfortunately I get  this error: "Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1026): x" How is that possible if they share the same X axis (Date)?

Comment: Do you have a geom or stats layer without any `data = ...` argument?

Comment: Nope, I specified it for both: 

`ggplot(mapping=aes(Date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Crime_occurrencies, colour = Crime), 
            data = Crime_data) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(Date, Unemployment.rate, col = "black"), data = Unemp_data) +
  facet_wrap(~Region,
             scales = "free_y")`

Comment: And if you change `aes(Date, Unemployment.rate, col = "black")` to `aes(Date, Unemployment.rate), col = "black"` (move the parenthesis)?

Comment: Same exact issue :s a guy suggested something that was working perfectly with the dataset he "made up" but it doesn't really work with my datasets for some reason... you can check it out here if you're curious https://community.rstudio.com/t/plotting-two-data-frames-with-different-y-scales-in-the-same-line-graph-in-r/92613

Comment: I don't see any obvious mistakes in the codes 3 comments back. Maybe it's a spelling error, a space in a column name, an object in your global environment that conflicts with the names in your data.frames. You could try to narrow down whether the crime data or unemployment data is causing the error by commenting out their geoms.

Comment: I think I am almost there!!! If you check the question I've just posted on here you can see how close we are to solving this haha

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your transformation of the df3 you are piping into ggplot is doing what you think it should. As you can see below, there are no columns for `Unemployment.date` or `Unemployment.rate`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df3 <- structure(list(
    Region = c(
        "West Midlands", "South West", "South East", 
        "South West", "West Midlands", "West Midlands", "London", "East Midlands", 
        "East of England", "South East"), 
    Crime.date = c("2019-02", "2019-07", "2020-07", "2019-06", "2020-06", "2019-03", 
                "2019-06", "2019-09", "2020-01", "2020-07"), 
    Crime = c("Burglary", "Robbery", "Anti-social behaviour", 
            "Robbery", "Anti-social behaviour", "Robbery", "Violence and sexual offences", 
            "Theft", "Robbery", "Violence and sexual offences"), 
    Crime_occurrencies = c(3365L, 204L, 25937L, 213L, 14612L, 1079L, 19976L, 5227L, 258L, 27559L), 
    Unemployment.date = c("2019-11", "2019-03", "2020-04", "2020-07", "2020-09", 
                      "2019-08", "2019-05", "2020-03", "2020-07", "2019-12"), 
    Unemployment.rate = c(4.31748261760943, 2.41576148488749, 3.01997997605704, 
                      3.79786892020692, 4.80407628492848, 3.98279027057451, 
                      4.2650375361128, 3.76788548732822, 3.72128619704797, 
                      3.21824018447441)), 
    row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", 
                                "data.frame"))

data <- df3 %>%
    count(Region, Crime.date, Crime, name = 'Crime_occurrencies') %>%
    mutate(Date = as.Date(paste0(Crime.date, '-01'))) 
data
#>             Region Crime.date                        Crime Crime_occurrencies
#> 1    East Midlands    2019-09                        Theft                  1
#> 2  East of England    2020-01                      Robbery                  1
#> 3           London    2019-06 Violence and sexual offences                  1
#> 4       South East    2020-07        Anti-social behaviour                  1
#> 5       South East    2020-07 Violence and sexual offences                  1
#> 6       South West    2019-06                      Robbery                  1
#> 7       South West    2019-07                      Robbery                  1
#> 8    West Midlands    2019-02                     Burglary                  1
#> 9    West Midlands    2019-03                      Robbery                  1
#> 10   West Midlands    2020-06        Anti-social behaviour                  1
#>          Date
#> 1  2019-09-01
#> 2  2020-01-01
#> 3  2019-06-01
#> 4  2020-07-01
#> 5  2020-07-01
#> 6  2019-06-01
#> 7  2019-07-01
#> 8  2019-02-01
#> 9  2019-03-01
#> 10 2020-06-01
```

I assume that what you are trying to do is to plot the transformed data and the non-transformed data in the same plot? To do that you have to specify the two data sets in the different geoms. You can then start combining the plots like this:

```
data <- df3 %>%
    count(Region, Crime.date, Crime, name = 'Crime_occurrencies') %>%
    mutate(Date = as.Date(paste0(Crime.date, '-01'))) 

    ggplot(data = data, aes(x = Date, y = Crime_occurrencies, colour = Crime)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_line(data = df3, mapping = aes(x = as.Date(paste0(Unemployment.date, '-01')), Unemployment.rate, color = "black")) +
    facet_wrap( ~ Region,
              scales = "free_y")
```

But the output of that is seemingly useless:
[image: without facet wrap]
[image: with facet wrap]

So to be honest, I am not sure how to continue to help. Maybe others have better ideas. However, I would suggest that rather than putting together a long string of code and then troubleshooting it if it doesn't work, to break it up into little pieces and test along the way that the code does what you think it should do.

<sup>Created on 2021-01-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot for the time you put into answering my question.
The output I am looking for is an overlay of the unemployment rate over the crime occurrencies, adding a Y axis on the right side for the unemployment rate scale (%). I am trying to analyse any correlations between unemployment rate and crime occurrencies across time. And yes, I am trying to plot the transformed data and the non transformed one in the same graph.